# Land cover analysis GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, random-forest

I want to do a time series analysis analysis for land cover classification.

For 2024 I am using this dataset COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR_HARMONIZED#description

I want to know what will the right Landsat dataset for 2014,2004, 1994,1984 and 1974.

Answer (score 0):

for landcover classification in long term extent like over the last 40 years, Landsat satellite series are the best option. Landsat collection 2 level 2 products are available in the Google Earth Engine platform which is already corrected radiometrically and atmospherically.